# How to get date name of day, month, date and year

Tags: c#

How can I generate a date in this format?

> Tuesday September 27, 2016

using code like this:

```
 TheDate = new DateTime(?????),
```

Comment: Look here https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Behesini, so quick question..does google not work from your region of the world.. come on now..

Comment: Down voted because this shows absolutely no research...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DateTime thisDate1= new DateTime(2016, 10, 27);
Console.WriteLine($"{thisDate1.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy")}");
```

Used sample from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)